# Is there a way of using reference column name in doctrine 2?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

I need to assing a value (a previously created entites Id)to reference column in a doctrine 2 model, For example

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="products")
 */
class product {

    /**
    * 
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="category")
    */
    protected $category;

    public function assignCategoryId($id) {
        $this->category_id=$id;
    }


}
```

I assume that category_id is created by doctrine 2 as referance column name,
Don't ask why I want to assign the id not the object itself, because it has to be this way. Is there a way to do this ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @Orbling's answer is correct you don't actually have to load the entity from the database. Instead you can use a reference:

```
// method on Product entity
public function setCategory(Category $category)
{
    $this->category = $category;
}

// then set the category on the product
$product->setCategory($entityManager->getReference('category', $categoryId));
```

You can find the [documentation here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html?highlight=getreference#reference-proxies).

Comment: OK, this solution sounds good but ,Because I try to implement ddd & cqrs in my project I don't want to use entity manager in the entity classes. I try to keep my entities as clean as possible.Any ideas?

Comment: Well you only use the entity manager to get the reference so you can just use `$category = $entityManager->getReference('category', $categoryId);` and pass the category into your domain instead of the categoryId

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you would create a `category` entity and assign it to the relationship property.

```
$category = $entityManager->find('category', $categoryID);

$product = new product();
$product->category = $category;
```

That would create the relationship I believe.

Comment: The Id that I want assign already exists sorry not to mentioned that. So that means the category entity was created previously. I just want to assign its id to the product entity.

Comment: In which case, you load the `category` from a repository class, rather than creating a new one. `$category = $entityManager->find('category', $categoryID);`